# How to tell babel to completely ignore es6 imports?

Tags: javascript, html, node-modules, babeljs

How to tell babel to completely ignore es6 imports ? I use nomodules with globals for old browsers and modules for new browser

Given `b.js`

```
  import a from "./a.js";
  const x = a.b();
```

I want

```
  // Nothing
  var x = a.b();
```

What I get

```
   require function call (undefined)
```

My html (simplified)

```
<html>
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <script nomodule src="./a.es5.min.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="./b.es5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="b.js"></script>
</html>
```

babel rc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": ["> 0.1%", "last 3 versions", "ie 10", "ie 11"]
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

partial package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  },
```

Comment: Have you found something for this?